# DNS Attack - 203.115.81.38 / 203.115.71.66

Tags: domain-name-system

I've noticed today that some of our companies clients' DNS servers were changed to 203.115.81.38 and 203.115.71.66 even thought they were still using DHCP. I wonder if this is some sort of an attack/malware etc. I have not been able to trace it down to anything yet but I thought sharing the addresses would help if this is a part of a wider problem.  I'm virus/malware scans on some of the computers and will update if I find anything useful.

Note: The DNS changes back to normal after a "ipconfig /renew"

Note 2: "Rogue Killer" found the source as "PUM.DNS". Looking to see how to remove it in mass scale.

Comment: Update: whatever ccaused this has changed the registry setting "DHCPNameServer" under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Comment: Those IP addresses are open resolvers in IP space owned by Pacenet India, so unless you can come up with a "good" explanation for why that change occurred I would be inclined to say this is something akin to [DNSChanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSChanger).

Comment: Agreed about DNSChanger, I need to find out how it got to us.

Comment: That's not really answerable, and the best advice I can give you is to review the DNSChanger symptoms and expect similar until a CERT advisory or somesuch is published. A rogue DHCP server is possible (ala DNSChanger), but the initial vector into your network is anyone's guess and there are countless possibilities.

Comment: Yes, not really answerable but it's a good internet-citizenship to report such occurrences as quick as possible. Not only here of course. If you're annoyed by it, please give me 2 days , I'll be happy to remove it. Unlike many people, I can't just ignore and wait for somebody else to solve it for me.

Comment: Not annoyed, and I think the question serves your intended purpose even if it gets flagged as a duplicate. People will contribute comments where possible.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the exploit your company has been exposed to, might be uniquely created for your company. Your windows group policy service should be able to control/revert th registry entry, but you still need to figure out what the attack vector is. Could be email, webpage advert, some 0-day somewhere, rogue DHCP service, etc...